# Python excepting input only if in range

Tags: python, error-handling, user-input

Hi I want to get a number from user and only except input within a certain range.

The below appears to work but I am a noob and thought whilst it works there is no doubt a more elegant example... just trying not to fall into bad habits!

One thing I have noticed  is when I run the program CTL+C will not break me out of the loop and raises the exception instead.

```
while True:
  try:
    input = int(raw_input('Pick a number in range 1-10 >>> '))
    # Check if input is in range
    if input in range(1,10):
      break
    else:
      print 'Out of range. Try again'
  except:
    print ("That's not a number")
```

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like two completely separate questions... It's best to ask one question at a time. If you get two answers: one to the first question, and another to the second, how do you know which to accept?

Comment: Do you know that `range(1,10)` doesn't include 10?  Your `raw_input` text suggests that you might want 10 to be acceptable.

Comment: Yes I knew 10 was out of the range, my mistake was to include it in the raw_input statement. Sorry just quickly put values in as an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ctrl+C raises a [`KeyboardInterruptException`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt), your `try … except` block catches this:

```
while True:
   try:
       input = int(raw_input('Pick a number in range 1-10 >>> '))
   except ValueError: # just catch the exceptions you know!
       print 'That\'s not a number!'
   else:
       if 1 <= input < 10: # this is faster
           break
       else:
           print 'Out of range. Try again'
```

Generally, you should just catch the exceptions you expect to happen (so no side effects appear, like your Ctrl+C problem). Also you should keep the `try … except` block as short as possible.

Comment: That should be `< 10` given `range(1, 10)` by OP

Comment: I always thought an else statement could only follow an if or elif statement. I now know that is not so.

Comment: @hemmy Did you know that `for` and `while` loops [may also be followed by an `else` statement](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) in some cases?

Comment: @lazyr No but I do now. Thanks! Also the example on the link is a about a million times shorter than the prime number program I wrote a few months ago... nice.

Answer (score 1):

There are several items in your code that could be improved.

(1) Most importantly, it's not a good idea to just catch a generic exception, you should catch a *specific* one you are looking for, and generally have as short of a `try`-block as you can.

(2) Also,

```
  if input in range(1,10):
```

would better be coded as

```
  if 1 <= input < 10:
```

as currently function [range()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) repeatedly creates a list of values form 1 to **9**, which is probably not what you want or need. Also, do you want to ***include*** value **10**? Your prompt seems to imply that, so then you need to adjust your call to `range(1, 11)`, as the list generated will *not* include the upper-range value. and the `if`-statement should be changed to `if 1 <= input <= 10:`

Comment: this is not a problem, it's just slower

Comment: But it *is* a valid answer to the first "question". The OP wrote "The below appears to work but I am a noob and thought whilst it works there is no doubt a more elegant example... just trying not to fall into bad habits!" Personally though I feel that the OPs first "question" should be deleted or moved into a separate question, perhaps on codereview.SE.

Comment: Thanks Levon. Everything you said makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code:

```
def read_int(prompt, min, max):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Error: wrong input')
        else:
            if(min <= val < max): # this is faster
                break
            else:
                print('Error: the value is not within permitted range (min..max)')
    return val    


v = read_int("Enter a number from -10 to 10: ", -10, 10)

print("The number is:", v)
```

Comment: Please explain the code, why it solves the problem, how, etc