# How to check for range in python while taking the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, validation, range

check whether the given input is in range or not,if  not break

Example- Take input between 1 to 100

```
lst=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
for i in lst:
    if 1<=lst[i]<=100:
        print(i)
```

is there any other way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python excepting input only if in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594605/python-excepting-input-only-if-in-range)

Comment: What's wrong with this way that you want different?

Comment: What is the idea behind `split()` here?

Comment: @po.pe you are right. This is an error obviously, because `split` returns a list and you can´t convert a list into a `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the range operator:

```
n = int(input())
if n in range(1, 1000):
    print(n)
```

Comment: Right, now I'm changing it.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
def in_range(min, max, input):
    if input in range(min,max):
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

cheers Styx

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((i>0) & (i<=100)):
    print(i)
else:
    break
```

Comment: This will produce an error, when you don´t use this code inside a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I am a new contributor, was just exploring how to write, was not knowing that that would not turn into a coded format

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator in Python and `if` is not a function, so you don't need the extra parentheses.